# High speed does not kill. Does acceleration do it ? or jerk?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, velocity, jerk

In a [recent question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/144736/why-doesnt-the-speed-of-earth-moving-through-space-kill-us) the OP asked why high speed will not kill us.
The [accepted answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/144736/why-doesnt-the-speed-of-earth-moving-through-space-kill-us/144738#144738), highly upvoted, stated very first that

> Speed doesn't kill us, but acceleration does.

The [second answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/144736/why-doesnt-the-speed-of-earth-moving-through-space-kill-us/144739#144739) (also well upvoted) concurs:

> The danger comes from acceleration, not velocity.

**Is that true?**

Two comments by [hdhondt](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/144736/why-doesnt-the-speed-of-earth-moving-through-space-kill-us/144738#comment300116_144738) and [Adam D. Ruppe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/144736/why-doesnt-the-speed-of-earth-moving-through-space-kill-us/144739#comment300402_144739) somewhat debunk it. but they
are only comments. They could not be answers, as the question
"[Why doesn't the speed of Earth (moving through space) kill us?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/144736/why-doesnt-the-speed-of-earth-moving-through-space-kill-us/144739#comment300402_144739)"  was not
about acceleration.
I wrote this question, and my answer to it (below), before I had read these
comments. Like many users, I do skip a lot of comments. When I finally
saw these comments already made, I wondered whether I should persist
with this question. The point seems important enough to justify it, considering the high popularity of this topic.

Comment: I was going to answer but the comment by Ruppe is correct. It is the differential acceleration between different parts of our bodies that either rips us apart or compress us until something breaks

Comment: @julianfernandez I mean to say that this comment by Ruppe is ok, but he does not say it exactly the way you do.

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54047/ Jerk causes vibration, which can be damaging. A steady acceleration can never cause a vibration.

Comment: @BenCrowell I doubt jerk by itself causes vibration. Jerk variations
across the body may do so (like other spatial variations). Like other
quantities, jerk may be harmful when applied to one part of a body and
then transmitted through varying forces (as it is varying
acceleration). The problem of local jerk is that it requires
adjustment of internal forces that balance acceleration and propagate
it across the body. Depending on jerk magnitude and characteristics of
the system (see the two-balls-and-a-spring model) there may be
oscillation before reaching a steady state.

Comment: @BenCrowell Just to be clear with a loose statement. One does not
apply jerk anywhere. One can only apply forces that cause
accelerations. When the force changes with time, so does the
acceleration, and jerk is just that variation. All I am saying is
that, if you change the force applied to some part of a system, the
system has to adjust to balance it (3rd law) by changing the balance
of its internal forces. There are local accelerations of parts (2nd
law) until the forces are balanced. This may cause oscillation that
may cause resonance vibration if repeated, depending on frequency and system

Answer (score 13):

Acceleration does not kill us any more than speed. If your head
and feet do not move at the same velocity long enough, whatever the
cause, you are in trouble. Velocity does not kill us when the whole body
has the same velocity.

Similarly, I doubt acceleration kills us when all parts of the body
accelerate, but without having to transmit forces. It is said in [a
comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/144736/why-doesnt-the-speed-of-earth-moving-through-space-kill-us#comment300257_144736):

> It's not the fall that kills you; it's the sudden stop at the end.

The sudden stop kills you because the deceleration (negative
acceleration) that stops you is actually caused by a force transmitted
through your body which cannot withstand it. The acceleration
throughout the fall, no matter how strong, which applies uniformly to
the whole body will not hurt it: you are in free fall.

If the same acceleration were produced by the pull of an engine
attached to your feets and pulling your whole body (even without
friction), rather than gravity applied uniformly to every atom of your
body, your body could well be torn to pieces.

I am no expert on [jerk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_%28physics%29), but I somehow doubt that it is any more
danger, despite contrary statements in [this accepted answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/144736/why-doesnt-the-speed-of-earth-moving-through-space-kill-us/144738#144738) and [this comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/144736/why-doesnt-the-speed-of-earth-moving-through-space-kill-us/144738#comment300500_144738)

The human body uses bones and muscles to maintain its integrity while
transmitting forces. The problem of jerk is that it changes the values
of forces, thus requiring muscles to adapt constantly.

But free fall satellite motion does have jerk, since the direction
of gravity is constanly changing, and its magnitude depends on
distance. This is generally true of non uniform gravity field.

I think, a good way of understanding what can hurt us is to model the
human body as two masses, head and feet, joined with a spring. If the
distance between the masses changes by more than, say, 5%, the human
model is considered dead. Now, if you add a strong structure, some
kind of [G-suit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-suit), that forcibly preserve the distance between head and
feet, thus carrying all forces that need to be transmitted, then the
human model is pretty safe.

Note that submitting the head and feet to
different acceleration can have [undesirable effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_Star_%28short_story%29) if the difference is important.  But if the body
is strong enough, it can sustain small differences which it compensate with internal cohesion forces.
So one might say that speed can be more dangerous than acceleration,
when it is an issue of uniformity across the body.

To place these issues on the level of personal experience: we do not feel
speed, but we do not feel acceleration either, or jerk. What we do experience
is forces propagating through our body, when our body accelerate
because it is submitted to forces applied only to some parts of it,
rather than uniformly. We experience the tension of the muscles that
preserve our body structure against these forces. And we perceive jerk
as a need to adapt muscle tension.

Comment: Since jerk is just the time-derivative of acceleration, you're correct that jerk alone wouldn't hurt you as long as it was uniform on all parts of your body. With every part of your body experiencing the same jerk as a function of time, all parts of your body would have the same acceleration at each moment and the same velocity at each moment (assuming they all had the same *initial* velocity), so in terms of the useful two-balls-and-a-spring model, the distance between the balls would remain constant so there'd be no stretching or compression of the spring.

Answer (score 4):

babou, this is really an extended comment to your own answer.

I think your answer is pretty much spot on, but I would simply the reasoning a bit. What kills you is when the distance between different parts of your body changes. You give the example of the separation between your head and feet changing by more than 5% (something exploited by hangmen over the centuries :-).

To get the position of any particular volume element $i$ within your body you simply integrate the equation:

$$ \frac{d^2\vec{x_i}}{dt^2} = \frac{1}{m_i}\vec{F}_i(t) $$

where $\vec{F}_i(t)$ is the net force on that volume element. In a fall, collision or whatever the force $\vec{F}(t)$ varies with position in the body and that's what causes the distance to change and the subsequent injury. You can Taylor expand the force as a function of time and separate it into acceleration, jerk, and higher order terms then argue which is the more important, but I think this is a bit of a red herring. If $\vec{F}(t)$ is the same throughout the body then there will be no distance change and no injury so it's not the magnitude of the acceleration, jerk, or whatever, but their inhomogeneity that kills you.

Comment: I fully agree. It is very artificial in general to isolate a function
from its derivatives. I am usually reluctant to use formulae when I
can avoid it, as I often see them as a poor excuse to bypass
understanding (and this is a good excuse for my failing memory of
whatever physics I learned). But you are right that it may sometimes
nails things in more firmly. They remain the skeleton of things.  My
way of doing it was the two-balls-and-a-spring model. See also the
view in http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54047#54059 and
comments.

Answer (score 3):

It really is the stress that kills you. Velocity, acceleration & jerk are all fine as long as they are spatially uniform. It is a postulate of general relativity that you can not even detect acceleration due to a uniform gravitational field, no matter how intense. However if the there are spatially non uniform forces applied to your body, then there will be stresses: tension, compression, shear or torsion. If they are high enough, something will give. This is what happens when you get hit, cut, stabbed, shot or even hanged, drawn and quartered.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, there isn't just one way in Newtonian mechanics to kill someone. You can cause as little or as much acceleration as you want. A few things worth analyzing are:

- Whiplash. If you're under constant acceleration and you reach a steady state (and aren't dead yet), a change in acceleration (jerk) could cause a whip effect.
- The Earth-Sun system. in a sun-centered inertial frame, people on the Earth don't die despite an acceleration on them.
- A centrifuge/jet with constant acceleration. By changing reference frames and using an equivalence principle, you can look at it like the weight of your body presses down on you until something squishes/breaks, at which point you cease to be.
- Knives, where high [relative] velocity can kill. So can low relative velocity!

So, these examples I think prove that a statement like "[X] doesn't kill, it's [Y]" where [x,y] are one of acceleration/jerk/velocity, is just too general to be correct. You have to look at the whole dynamics of the situation.

Comment: The killing issue is only an image. It originates with the previous
question that motivated this one. About the whiplash: there will be
none if the change of acceleration applies uniformly to your whole
body. The issue is always homogeneity, whether for speed, acceleration
or jerk. If you consider the Earth-sun system, people on earth are
submitted to an acceleration, but also to jerk since this acceleration
keeps changing its direction.

Answer (score 2):

If you fly head first into a wall, at the moment of impact the top of your head will accelerate very rapidly while the est of your body continues to travel at a constant speed until they make contact with the wall. Clearly having different parts of your body rapidly accelerate in different direction will lead to some very large forces on various parts of your anatomy and is not going to end well. This is not the same thing as jerk which would be about the difference in acceleration of a single part of your body at different times. If your entire body receives exactly the same acceleration, this will not lead to any internal strains and won't cause you any problems. In practice however the only external force capable of delivering a truly uniform acceleration is gravity, as it acts on each part of you body directly and in proportion to its mass. This means that often it is enough to simply look at the magnitude of the forces acting on your body and not look to carefully at how they are acting and treat gravity is an exception, so the the other answers are not so much wrong as being approximate.